# Catch an error from tar and continue processing

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm looping through a list of .tar.gz files, untar them and do some analysis with them. So far so good. The problem is, when some of the files are corrupt, `untar` throws an error and the processing stops.

My code is like that:

```
f <- dir(path.to.files, pattern=".tar.gz")
for(k in 1:length(f)){
  # make sure the temporary dir is empty
  file.remove(dir(path = tempdir(), full.names = TRUE)
  untar(f[k], exdir = tempdir())
  # do some analisys with the extracted files
}
```

I would rather catch the error from untar, skip that corrupt file, and simply continue my loop. I already tried to use `try` and `tryCatch` but without luck.

Is there a way of telling `untar` to throw a warning instead of an error?

Comment: Please include a description of what happened when you "tried to use `try` and `tryCatch`." This might help to diagnose the problem. Also, there is an extras argument in `untar` that passes options to the tar program. Perhaps the tar program itself may have an option to fail more gracefully.

Comment: `try` only leads to an additional warning: for (i in seq_len(ceiling(size/512L))) but I've figured out that I used `tryCatch`in the wrong way. I simply put it in front of the untar command without evaluating the error. Putting an error handling function inside of tryCatch solved the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue the loop by adding `next` to the finally argument of `tryCatch`. Consider the following example. The loop runs from 1 to 3 and prints the iteration value. When the value is equal to 2, R tries to untar the file "untitled-3.synctex1.gz", which does not exist in my current working directory

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
  if(i == 2) tryCatch(untar("untitled-3.synctex1.gz"), finally=next)
}
```

> [1] 1
>   [1] 2
>    Show Traceback
>
> Rerun with Debug
>    Error in gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
>   In gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") :
>     cannot open compressed file 'untitled-3.synctex1.gz', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>   [1] 3

We see the error message and the warning, but the loop continues to the next iteration and prints the third value.

Comment: Nice. I came up with a similar solution, adding ´NULL` to the third argument of ´tryCatch` in and then evaluating if the return value of ´tryCatch´ is NULL.